# GatsbyJS Page opens blank when opening from URL (using blog navigation works appropriately)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I work on a blog site using GatsbyJS framework. Recently, I faced problem, when I realized that http://codeforheaven.com/blog/ page opens blank, but only when I type it's URL in a browser. When I click Blog link on a home page http://codeforheaven.com/ it works good, same when I come back from any of the articles (ie. http://codeforheaven.com/blog/flex-sticky-footer). What's more, I have no such problem in development process at localhost.

My `blog.js` file looks like this. Project was created following gatsby tutorials and documentation.

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../layout/Layout"
import BlogTeaser from "../components/blog-teaser/blog-teaser";
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"
import ContentPage from '../layout/ContentPage';
import IconsWaterfall from '../components/icons-waterfall/icons-waterfall';

// definision of styled elements

const IndexPage = ({
    data: {
      allMarkdownRemark: { edges },
    },
    }) => {
      const Posts = edges
        .filter(edge => !!edge.node.frontmatter.date) // You can filter your posts based on some criteria
        .map(edge => <BlogTeaser key={edge.node.id} teaserData={edge.node} />);

      return (
        <>
          <Helmet>
            <meta charSet="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
            <title>Code for Heaven - BLOG</title>
            <link rel="canonical" href="http://codeforheaven.com/blog" />
          </Helmet>
          <Layout>
            <ContentPage>
              <BlogContainer>
                  <SubpageHeader>
                    <Link to="/">Code for Heaven</Link>
                  </SubpageHeader>
                  <PageHeader>Blog</PageHeader>
                  {Posts}
              </BlogContainer>
              <IconsWaterfallWrapper>
                <IconsWaterfall/>
              </IconsWaterfallWrapper>
            </ContentPage>
          </Layout>
        </>
      )
    }

export default IndexPage

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    allMarkdownRemark(sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          excerpt(pruneLength: 250)
          frontmatter {
            date(formatString: "DD/MM")
            path
            title
            description
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

EDIT:
**gatsby-node.js**

```
exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/blogTemplate.js`)

  const result = await graphql(
  /* ... */
   )

  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`)
    return
  }

  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.frontmatter.path,
      component: blogPostTemplate,
      context: {}
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: You should be calling `createPage` for each of your blog posts in `gatsby-node.js`. Are you doing that? If so, you should have a file for each at `public/blog/<slug>.html` after running `gatsby build`; are those present with content?

Comment: yes, I do. As a result I have `public/blog/<slug>/index.html` in public.

Comment: Okay, seems like you have something wrong with your Apache configuration then because it's returning an empty response (headers with no body, and a `Content-Length: 0`).